# Apply CenterDot on List on List

Tags: list-manipulation

Given

```
lis={{Superscript[2,2], Superscript[3,1]}, {Superscript[
 13,1]}, {Superscript[2,1], Superscript[7,1]}, {Superscript[
 3,1], Superscript[5,1]}}
```

```
Apply[CenterDot, lis, 1]
```

gives me wrong results for lists of Length one. How can I just keep the the single powers as they are?

Comment: We can refine the definition with `CenterDot[a_] := a;`, and use `CenterDot[a_] =.;` to remove the new definition.

Comment: `CenterDot @@@ lis /. CenterDot[x_] :> x`

Comment: Great! But where can I find something about removing definitions in Help?

Comment: One can also do `# /. {{x_} :> x, x_List :> CenterDot @@ x} & /@ lis` ...

Comment: Wow! This is interesting. You showed me how to combine conditions in Replace.

Comment: Why not compiling a proper answer?

Comment: For removing definitions you can read [Unset](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html) and [Managing Definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#16933).

Comment: You can also do: `If[Length[#] == 1, Times @@ #, Apply[CenterDot, #]] & /@lis`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you're getting are not wrong. CenterDot has no built in evaluation rules, but it does have built in presentation rules. Let's look at the FullForm for a simplified version of your example:

```
Apply[CenterDot, {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}, 1]//FullForm
```

`List[CenterDot[a], CenterDot[a, b], CenterDot[a, b, c]]`

It just so happens that with 1 argument, there is no place to put the \[CenterDot] symbol. Something simple that you could do to maintain consistency is to define how to format CenterDot with single arguments:

```
Format[CenterDot[a_]] := a
```

In the above example, we will get the same FullForm result (the CenterDot head will still be there for the singleton case), but we'll get the appearance that you want.